# PHP version that allows property assignment BEYOND straight literals?

Tags: php, parsing, class, properties, version

I am new to PHP, but very experienced with programming. Looking at the PHP web site page on properties: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php I saw this example.

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
   // invalid property declarations:
   public $var1 = 'hello ' . 'world';
   public $var2 = <<<EOD
hello world
EOD;
   public $var3 = 1+2;
   public $var4 = self::myStaticMethod();
   public $var5 = $myVar;

   // valid property declarations:
   public $var6 = myConstant;
   public $var7 = array(true, false);

   // This is allowed only in PHP 5.3.0 and later.
   public $var8 = <<<'EOD'
hello world
EOD;
}
?>
```

Running this example returns the error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in test.php on line 5

In fact, the php.net example for SimpleClass contains all sort of property assignments that are NOT to straight literals, all of which seem to raise errors; phpinfo() says the version is PHP Version 5.2.4.

Is this a problem associated with the PHP version?

Comment: Did you see the comment that says "**invalid** property declarations"?

Comment: Someone "very experienced with programming" would know how to _read_ the code he's writing.

Comment: Also, none of these are assignments; they're declarations.

Comment: Can you make sure that error_reporting = E_ALL and display_errors = 1 in your php.ini? Add any errors you are receiving in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The example you quoted reads:

> // invalid property declarations:

above the lines that don't work. Seems pretty self-explanatory.

A few lines further down the page:

> Unlike heredocs, nowdocs can be used in any static data context,
>   including property declarations.
>
> Example #2: Example of using a nowdoc to initialize a property
>
> ```
> <?php
> class foo {
>    // As of PHP 5.3.0
>    public $bar = <<<'EOT'
> bar
> EOT;
> }
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Truly unbelievable that I missed that. Thanks for the time guys, just very busy with the project and just couldn't conceive of someone putting up a sample of INVALID code before valid code. Tomolak, what can I say? This is the kind of comment you leave when you don't have to meet people face to face. I've never regretted being polite and considerate. Apparently you've never made a dumb mistake, in which case I'll be sure to hire you for my next big project. Hobbs, Harsh thanks for the extra info.

Comment: I meet people face to face all the time. Doesn't make what I said any less true.